# Horizontal rather than vertical display

Tags: filepond

I want to display multiple file uploads horizontally rather than the default vertical. I don't see any mention of this in the documentation.

Comment: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/style/#grid-layout

Answer (score 2):

The `v4.0.0` has incorporated the grid layout which allows having a horizontal layout.

Look at the documentation [here](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/style/#grid-layout).

You can also look at the issue being talked [over here](https://github.com/pqina/filepond/issues/134)

I hope it helps.

Comment: If only they were using flex instead of calculating manually the position of everything in js.. This solution sadly works terribly when you have different file types which will have a different render height